# Encrypting a URL Coldfusion and JQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, datatables

Stack Overflow Users,

I have a server side JQuery Datatable and I am attempting to encrypt the record ID. I've used this method on basic data tables in a CFLOOP but I have not been able to do it in JavaScript.

Below is my current code.

```
                {
                    "targets": 1,
                    "data": "LAST_NAME",
                    <cfset L = "'+ data+'"/>
                    <cfset l_id = Encrypt(L,myKey,'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding','HEX') />
                    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) 
                    {return '<a href="candidate/?svr=#l_id#">'+ data+'</a>';},
                },
```

When I decrypt the url, it displays **+ data+**. When I change it to use the **L** vairble, then I get the correct ID number but it is not encrypted

```
{return '<a href="candidate/?svr=#L#">'+ data+'</a>';}
```

I know it has something to do with using CFSCRIPT yet I am unclear how to use this. Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried `<cfset L = data>`, assuming `data` is a coldfusion variable.You question lack the context. If you can clarify it more that could help in someone helping you.

Comment: Ill try to explain, if I pass the varible L to the JavaScript the link will show the correct unencrypted user id like 8091. But, if I try to encrypt the L varible and pass JavaScript the l_id varible, it will decrypt literally,  + data+. Its like JavaScript will allow the simple cfset but the tried and true encrypted cfset doesn't work.

Comment: If you're trying to encrypt a *javascript* variable from ColdFusion - that isn't possible. ColdFusion is a server side language. It can't access Javascript code/variables and vice versa.

Comment: ColdFusion has an option called cfscript, I'm just not sure how to use it.  Maybe a better approach would be to encrypt the id on the database call before it's sent to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Although, there are many methods for encrypting the url, I found in my case the best method was to intercept the EMPLOYEE_ID in the JSON request prior to the JavaScript hand off.

```
<cfset ED_ID = Encrypt(EMPLOYEE_ID,myKey,'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding','HEX')/>
    <cfset obj = {
        "EMPLOYEE_ID" = variables.ED_ID,
```

As you can see from the above example, the Employee_ID is modified before passing it to the JSON response. The successfully encrypts the employee id and creates the more secure URL.